# snowflake: remove access to drop a table to a role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a role with the following grants

```
GRANT 
USAGE,
CREATE FUNCTION,
CREATE PROCEDURE,
CREATE TABLE,
CREATE VIEW,
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE,
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW,
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE,
ON SCHEMA dbname.schemaname TO ROLE role_test;
```

Now using this role, i am able to create table or replace a table and also drop a table.

How  to stop someone to DROP table.

Answer (score 1):

The owner role of the table will have DROP permissions. So it's not possible to stop someone from dropping the table they created.

You may need to change the ownership of the table to another role.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-drop-an-object-as-a-role-other-than-the-object-creator